# Testing custom hooks react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

Im learning react testing and i have this hook i want to test but i have no idea how

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useFetch = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async (url: string) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = await response.data.data;
      setLoading(false);
      return data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error.name !== 'AbortError') {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return { error, loading, fetchData };


};
```

what i got so far but this is just me trying stuff cuzz there is no much help online that is good for my case

```
import { useFetch } from '../../hooks/useFetch';
import mockAxios from 'jest-mock-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('useFetch', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    mockAxios.reset();
  });
  it('fetches successfully data from an API', async () => {
    const { result,waitFor  } = renderHook(() => useFetch());
    let responseObj = { data: 'test response' };
    
    mockAxios.mockResponseFor({ url: '/get' }, responseObj);
    expect(result.current.error).toBe(null);
    await expect(result.current.fetchData('react')).resolves.toBe(responseObj);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to call `setState` mutate the state. We need to use [act()](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act) function to

> make sure all updates related to these “units” have been processed and applied to the DOM before you make any assertions.

Since your `fetchData` returns a promise, we need to use `async act(...)`, you need React version at least `v16.9.0-alpha.0`. For more info about `act()` function, see [react-act-example](https://github.com/mrdulin/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md).

`react-hook-testing-library` re-export [act()](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#act) function from [chosen renderer](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/installation#renderer).

Besides, I just use `jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce()` to mock `axios.get()` method without installing any extra package.

Note: I return `response.data`, not `await response.data.data`.

Now, the working unit test should be:

`useFetch.ts`:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useFetch = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async (url: string) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = response.data;
      setLoading(false);
      return data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error.name !== 'AbortError') {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message);
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return { error, loading, fetchData };
};
```

`useFetch.test.ts`:

```
import { useFetch } from './useFetch';
import axios from 'axios';
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

describe('useFetch', () => {
  it('fetches successfully data from an API', async () => {
    const mockData = { data: 'test response' };
    const axiosGetSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: mockData })
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFetch());

    expect(result.current.error).toBe(null);

    await act(async () => {
      await expect(result.current.fetchData('react')).resolves.toEqual(mockData);
    })

    axiosGetSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74063562/useFetch.test.ts (17.219 s)
  useFetch
    ✓ fetches successfully data from an API (16 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |   83.33 |        0 |     100 |   81.25 |                   
 useFetch.ts |   83.33 |        0 |     100 |   81.25 | 16-18             
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        21.31 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
```

Comment: this gives me the error " Cannot spy the get property because it is not a function; undefined given instead"

Comment: @ludinj Double check, make sure you don't have a `__mocks__/axios` and other things may affect the test

Comment: if i delete the __mocks__/axios.ts then i get this error 
  "  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ludin\Desktop\Training Program\week-9-project\src\__mocks__\axios.ts'"  this is really hard to configure